# How do I use contenttools to edit html with a (buttons) links?

Tags: wysiwyg

I using contenttools script.

http://getcontenttools.com/demo

I have following code:
How can I edit "READ MORE" text?

```
<div data-name="main-content-1" data-editable="" class="home3-box1">
<h3>
    Test test test
</h3>
<p>
    Test test test Test test test Test test test
</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-default">READ MORE</a></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0x15nshk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can try here, the simplest of which is placing the button within an editable text tag such as a paragraph, e.g:

```
<p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-default">READ MORE</a> 
</p>
```

Or if you'd prefer to not have the additional `p` element you can mark the `a` tag as a text element type like so:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-default" data-ce-tag="text">READ MORE</a>
```

Note the use of the `data-ce-tag` attribute here to flag that the element should be parsed as a `ContentEdit.Text` element.

You might also want to consider applying some restrictions to the tag in terms of how it can be edited, in the latest version of [ContentTools (1.2.5)](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/releases/tag/1.2.5) this is now possible but experimental. As a simple example of how you might approach this:

```
// Define a limited set of tools that can be used with buttons
var BUTTON_TOOLS = [
    ['align-left', 'align-center', 'align-right'], 
    ['undo', 'redo']
    ];

ContentEdit.Root.get().bind('focus', function (element) {
    var tools;

    // Whenever a button is selected switch to the button only tools
    if (element.domElement().containsClass('btn')) {
        tools = BUTTON_TOOLS;
    } else {
        tools = ContentTools.DEFAULT_TOOLS;
    }

    if (ContentTools.EditorApp.get().toolbox().tools() !== tools) {
        ContentTools.EditorApp.get().toolbox().tools(tools);
    }

    // Limit the behaviour of the button so it can't be moved, merged or removed
    if (element.domElement().classList.contains('btn')) {
        element.can('drag', false);
        element.can('drop', false);
        element.can('remove', false);
        element.can('merge', false);
    } 
});
```

Documentation for the different element behaviours is provided here: http://getcontenttools.com/api/content-edit#behaviours