# How to edit nested HTML in ContentTools wysiwyg JavaScript editor

Tags: html, configuration, nested, wysiwyg, content-tools

This Question was conceived when studying the answer to [StackOverflow question #37370944](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370944/how-do-i-use-contenttools-to-edit-html-with-a-buttons-links).

In my database, I have html markup, for which I'd like to give my html-agnostic web-app users to have a tool to edit it in a browser. This is referential materials, mostly notes and source citations. For this purpose I use an html form generated by the server side, and a JavaScript widget, i.e. ContentTools, which, on form submit-button click event, collects a string of resulting html markup from the edited region and sets it as value on the designated  form field.

The problem is that, as I discovered, ContentTools doesn't allow editing of the nested markup, e.g. inside html block elements, i.e. `<div>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, etc., out of the box or at all (I do not know). To demonstrate this, I modified a forked JSFiddle example provided by the StackOverflow question #37370944 mentioned above. So, please [take a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voltel/nxw7k9z5/).

There are three link-buttons described in the markup:

1. The first one is a stand-alone `<a>` which is as an immediate child of the wrapper div holding the edited region content (`<div data-name="main-content" data-editable="">`).
2. The second link-button is placed inside a nested `<div>` with set attribute `data-ce-tag="text"` to presumably enable recognition of the content as editable text.
3. The third link-button is placed inside `<p>` tag which is as an immediate child of the wrapper div.

All three link-buttons wrapper-elements (`<a>`, `<div>` and `<p>`) have special css class "js-has-anchor" to enable change of the tools on the tool panel via the "focus" event bound to the editor Root.

It turns out, the "focus" event is only triggered for `<p>` (case 3) elements in the document, not for `<div>` (case 2) or `<a>` (case 1). As a result, only for the 3rd link-button a set of panel tools is updated. Moreover, the `<div>` and `<a>` elements cannot be edited.

The html markup in my database is mostly a mess, previously edited in CKEditor in some cases, or entered directly by hand. I'd like to make all available content to be readily recognized by ContentTools as editable (not "static") including nested structures similar to the one in the sample below. The main idea of the provided html sample is that it's a nested structure (not just a list of `<hN>`, `<p>` and `<img>` elements as in the edited *page__content* region from [the ContentTools demo](http://getcontenttools.com/demo)), every `<section>` consists only of `<article>` elements, and each article consists of a header(`<hN>`) and either another section, or a wrapping `<div>` holding all the content of this article. 
And I'd like this structure not to be broken if it is already in place, and ideally enforced if it is not there yet. 
But all this is a single region which is persisted in one text field of my database (no separate regions are possible).

```html
<h1>Section 1 heading</h1>
<section class="mb-5">
    <article>
        <h2>Sub-Section 1.1 heading</h2>
        <section class="mb-3">
            <article>
                <h3>Chapter 1.1.1 heading</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="pic.jpg" alt="Some text" style="width:100%">
                        <figcaption>Fig.1 - Picture Caption</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <p>Some other text</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h3>Chapter 1.1.2 heading</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <figure>
                    <img src="another_pic.jpg" alt="Some other text" style="width:100%">
                    <figcaption>Fig.2 - picture caption</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </section>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Sub-Section 1.2 heading</h2>
        <section class="mb-3">
            <article>
                <h3>Chapter 1.2.1 heading</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                    <p>Some other text</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h3>Chapter 1.2.2 heading</h3>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
```

So, is it at all possible with ContentTools, and I'd appreciate an example with "customized" tool panel content from the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voltel/nxw7k9z5/) to work for all link-buttons (and all of them be editable), not only for the one wrapped in the `<p>` tag.